# how to pass a path with sub folders using Github API

Tags: c#, rest, github, github-api

I am trying to retrieve some blob information using ***github rest api***. Being exactly http://develop.github.com/p/object.html the **blob/show/:user/:repo/:tree_sha/:path**
 I get problems when requesting a file that is in a sub folder.

 for example:

> http://github.com/api/v2/xml/blob/show/ ***user*** / ***repository*** / ***tree_shar*** /folder/subfolder/file.htm
>
> http://github.com/api/v2/xml/blob/show/alexanderbeletsky/blog.beletsky.net/f79e40c279db8f02d1ecec263305520b880261a3/Linkedin/Summary.htm

doesnt work.

how should the :path look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your request looks just fine and you were using the `:path` variable correctly. But you used the wrong SHA. The SHA you used is from a commit. You need to use a tree SHA. You also need to make sure to use a tree SHA where the file `Linkedin/Summary.htm` exists. The correct SHA is: `b0215ec2989369ad39f81e11ecdd29ddf2be83c8`

And the full request:

https://github.com/api/v2/xml/blob/show/alexanderbeletsky/blog.beletsky.net/b0215ec2989369ad39f81e11ecdd29ddf2be83c8/Linkedin/Summary.htm

Edit: I totally forgot to tell how to get the tree SHA: First I checked out your repo from github:

`git clone https://github.com/alexanderbeletsky/blog.beletsky.net.git`

Then I checked the most recent commit of `Linkedin/Summary.htm`:

```
git log -n 1 --pretty=raw Linkedin/Summary.htm
commit 93318187799f4b18662954519e7367ad0861924e
tree b0215ec2989369ad39f81e11ecdd29ddf2be83c8
parent 32c30665d5d1c9ff14ada1565b16f9019ebe2dcf
author alexander.beletsky <alexander.beletsky@gmail.com> 1298272994 +0200
committer alexander.beletsky <alexander.beletsky@gmail.com> 1298272994 +0200
```

And there it was: `tree b0215ec2989369ad39f81e11ecdd29ddf2be83c8`